# Find the vector which minimize distance in $\mathrm{R^4}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the next problem:

Let $W \subset \mathbb{R^4}$ the subspace genereted by the next two vectors:

$$ W:= \text{span} \left\{ [1,1,0,0]^{T},[1,1,1,1]^{T} \right\}. $$

Find $w\in W$ such that minimize $\|w-v\|$ with $v = [1,2,3,4]^T$.

I know that the vector $w$ would have the form

$$ w= s\begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           1 \\
           0 \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix} + 
       t \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           1 \\
           1 \\
           2
         \end{bmatrix}$$

or $w = (s+t)\hat{x} + (s+t)\hat{y} + t\hat{z} + 2t\hat{k}$, so, to minimize the norm I thought to use calculus; Defining the distance between $w$ and $v$

$$ d:= \left[(s+t-1)^2 + (s+t-2)^2 + (t-3)^2 + (2t-4)^2\right]^{1/2}$$

and then the derivatives respect to $s$ and $t$ to put together an equation system

$$\frac{\partial d}{\partial s} = 0$$

$$\frac{\partial d}{\partial t} = 0$$.

I found numerical values for $s$ and $t$ but I would like to know if there is a shorter way, because the equation system I got was very hard to solve.

thanks.

Comment: Consider the fact that $d$ is minimized if and only if $d^2$ is minimized. Performing the same operations on $d^2$ should produce a linear system.

Comment: Of course! I never thought about that extra condition, in fact the new system seems much easier to solve! thank you very much

Comment: Have you studied orthogonal projections yet?

Comment: By the way, it shouldn't really matter. The derivative of $\sqrt{f(x)}$ is $\frac{f'(x)}{2\sqrt{f(x)}}$ so solving for a zero root ignores the weird denominator anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with perpendicular projection. All you need is an orthogonal basis for $W$, then project the vector $v$ on those two basis vectors. The sum of these projections will give you the vector that is closest to $v$.

First, we need two orthogonal vector from $W$. Let's use
$$w_1=[1,1,1,1]^T$$
$$w_2=-1\cdot[1,1,0,0]^T+1\cdot[1,1,1,1]^T=[-1,-1,1,1]^T$$
So $w_1,w_2\in W$ and they are orthogonal.
$$<w_1,w_2>=-1-1+1+1=0$$
Let's evaluate the perpendicular projection of $v$ on $w_1$ and $w_2$.
$$v_{w_1}=\frac{<v,w_1>}{<w_1,w_1>}w_1=\frac{10}4w_1=\left[\frac52,\frac52,\frac52,\frac52\right]^T$$
$$v_{w_2}=\frac{<v,w_2>}{<w_2,w_2>}w_2=\frac{4}4w_2=\left[-1,-1,1,1\right]^T$$
Now let's sum those projections
$$w=v_{w_1}+v_{w_2}=\left[\frac32,\frac32,\frac72,\frac72\right]^T$$
$w$ is the closest vector of $W$ from $v$ since $w-v$ is perpendicular of $W$. The distance is
$$\|w-v\|=\left\|\left[\frac12,\frac12,-\frac12,-\frac12\right]^T\right\|=1$$

Comment: Thank you, once I analized your procedure I think it is a little obvious if I imagine the situation in R^3, as you may noticed I'm not very good in linear algebra xd